# abrir un archivo jasper en un .jar

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jar

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio en `java`, la cual necesito al mismo tiempo que me genere reportes y estoy usando `jasper reports`, lo que pasa es que no me reconoce la ruta del archivo *.jasper*, me aparece el error `file not found exception` sin embargo si ejecuto el proyecto desde netbeans me lee el archivo sin ningún inconveniente, adjunto el fragmento de código en el cual estoy llamando los .jasper, espero y me puedan ayudar.

```
private String driver,url,db,usr,pass;

private static Connection conexion;
public GestorReportes(){
    driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    db="tallercitas";
    usr="";
    pass="";
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+db+"";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://***.***.***.***;databaseName=dbname;user=user;password=******");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de conexion " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void ejecutarReporte(String archivo){
    try{
        String Reporte="src\\reportes\\"+archivo;
        //JasperReport masterReport=(JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(Reporte);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Reporte);
        //Reporte=(JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(Reporte);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Reporte, null,conexion);

        JasperViewer jView=new JasperViewer(jasperPrint,false);

        jView.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el archivo jasper se encuentra dentro de tu JAR, tal y como parece ser por lo que comentas, debes cargarlo como un recurso dentro del CLASSPATH de la aplicación y no como un archivo en el sistema de archivo. Este es el motivo por el cual sí te funciona el IDE, ya que este lo que hace es compilar las clases y moverlas, junto a los recursos, a un directorio el cual puede ser localizado en el sistema de archivos como cualquier otro directorio.

Para solventar esto y que te funcione también cuando los recursos estén empaquetados dentro de un JAR debes hacer algo así:

```
public void ejecutarReporte(String archivo) {
    try {
        // asumiendo que archivo es algo como reporte.jasper
        // MiClase es la clase donde se encuentra este método
        InputStream reporteInputStream = MiClase.class.getResourceAsStream("/reportes/" + archivo);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporteInputStream, null, conexion);
        JasperViewer jView = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        jView.setVisible(true);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, eso soluciono mi problema y probablemente otros inconvenientes que tengo, muchas gracias

Comment: Pues que bien. Un abrazo!!

Answer (score 0):

si quieres abrir un reporte desde un fichero o ruta externa

```
InputStream jr = JRLoader.getFileInputStream("C:/MG/" + nombre + ".jasper");
```